# How to rerender child component every time the parent is rerendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, render

This is my render method in App.js:

```
render() {
console.log('APP Mounted', this.state.searchedBooks)
return (
  <div className="app">
    <Route exact path='/' render={()=> (
      <ListBooks 
        books={this.state.books} 
        handleChangeCategory={(choice) => this.handleChangeCategory(choice)}
      />
    )}/>
    <Route path='/search' render={({ history }) => (
      <SearchBook 
        handleChangeCategory={(choice) => this.handleChangeCategory(choice)}
        handleSearchBook={(query) => this.handleSearchBook(query)}
        searchedBooks={this.state.searchedBooks}
      />
    )}/>
  </div>
)}
```

I have *searchedBook* state that keeps updating when a new query arrives, and therefore also rerenders *App.js*. The log at the top of the *render()* method works as expected.

The problem is, that my child component *SearchBook* is not rerendering when *App.js* is rerendered and therefore doesn't receive the latest *this.state.searchedBooks*

In *SearchBook.js* I added the *componentDidMount()* method to reset the state:

```
class SearchBook extends Component {

state = {
    query : '',
    books : []
}

componentDidMount(){ 
    console.log('Mounted')        
    this.setState(() => ({
        books: this.props.searchedBooks
    }))
}

updateQuery = (query) => {
    this.setState(() => ({
        query: query
    }))
}


onChangeQuery = query => {
    this.updateQuery(query)
    this.props.handleSearchBook(query)
}

render(){
    const { query, books } = this.state;

    return()
        
}}
```

But this doesn't work as the whole *SearchBook* component doesn't get rerendered after my *searchedBooks* state is updated in App.js.

When I manually access a different URL (here the home route) and go back to the /search route, obviously the component gets rerendered and it works.

So how do I make the child of App.js rerender as well?

Comment: Please show `SearchBook`.

Comment: @cbr I added the rest of SearchBook, though the rest isn't really relevant as I just want the whole child to rerender.

Comment: Don't copy the searchedBooks props into the SearchBook's state. Just use this.props.searchedBooks in render() and it will re-render as the parent props re-render.

Comment: Well, I thought I already tried it. Thank you very much. It works now.